# Horizontal alignment of 3 boxes in a wrapper

Tags: html, css

Hey,
I'm playing around with CSS3 at the moment and ran into a problem, using three div boxes.
I want them to be horizontally aligned in a wrapper box without having to specify the exact margins.

My approach has been this:

```
.box1 {
background: gray;
float: left;
width: 250px;
padding: 3px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.box2 {
background: gray;
float: left;
width: 250px;
padding: 3px;
margin: 0 auto; 
}

.box3 {
background: gray;
float: left;
width: 250px;
padding: 3px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

which results in the three boxes, aligned left to wrapper box without any margins between them. But I want the boxes to set the margins, so the boxes are centered in the red wrapper. Any ideas to do this without exact pixel settings?

Comment: Do you want the wrapped boxes to be centered in the wrapper? otherwise remove margin: 0 auto; and only set it on the wrapping div

Comment: That's what I want, yep.

Comment: Wrap the three boxes in a invisible div element, center the div element with margin:0 auto; and then adjust the margin in your boxes

Comment: The current, intentionally visible wrapper is already centered. Shouldn't that be the same?

Comment: Not if you have an explicit size on that visible wrapper, and you want your elements to be centered inside that wrapper.

Comment: Current wrapper's that:
    .content {
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: medium;
 background: red;
 width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
    }

Comment: Maybe I should let someone better at css answer your question then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm. Well you can't use margin-auto on floated values.
I'd give them exact pixel margins. More control.

Do you expect to not know the width of the red-wrapper?

Also, all those classes are the same, just call it "box" and reuse that for all your boxes.

```
.box{
  background: gray;
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px;
}

<div id="red-wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

EDIT:
(was thinking about this. Thought I'd share a different structure that might give you the results you're looking for.)

```
.bigbox{
  width:33%;
  float:left;
}

.box {
  background: gray;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px auto;
}

#red-wrapper {
  width:100%;
  background:red;
  overflow:hidden;
}

<div id="red-wrapper">
  <div class="bigbox">
    <div class="box"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bigbox">
    <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  <div class="bigbox">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CCNqg/6/)

Comment: Okay, so I definitely have to calculate all the margins? Sucks.

Comment: Wow this answered what I was about to ask again.

Answer (score 0):

If its suitable for your purpose, inline-block might help. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CCNqg/).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I used Flex box.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp
you can wrap it to fit elements when zooming in.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't provide link-only answers: if the link gets broken, the answer becomes irrelevant. Put the most important bits to your post directly: this way, it is also easier and quicker to follow. Best regards